# Decompile tool for .net core which coded in .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, decompiling, decompiler

Does anyone know about a decompiler tool for .net core which is written in .net core?
All the tools I found are written in .net framework.

My application is written in .net core and I prefer not to require my users to install also .net framework.

Thanks

Comment: What is your target operating system? All current Windows versions have .NET Framework 4.x built-in, so your users won't have to install any extra.

Comment: I'm targeting to Linux

Comment: Tool recommendation is off-topic, but Avalonia ILSpy is a free option, https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvaloniaILSpy/

Answer (score 0):

.NET Reflector
supports C#7, .NET 4.7.2, and .NET Core and Standard.

[here](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/)